# Position realtive/absolute cause overlap over navbar

Tags: css, tailwind-css

```
import React from "react";
import img from '../../../public/images/home/desktop/image-speaker-zx9.png'
export default function Zspeaker()
{

    return(
<div className=" mx-auto mt-6 bg-orange-400  w-[85%] rounded-xl ">
  <div className=" flex flex-col lg:gap-20 justify-around items-center rounded-xl mx-auto w-[90%]   lg:flex-row lg:px-20">
    <div className=" relative">
    <img className="  w-48 lg:w-64  5" src={img} alt="speaker" />
    </div>
    <div className="items-center flex flex-col lg:items-start text-white py-7">
      <h1 className="text-center text-5xl">ZXP<br></br>Speaker</h1>
      <p className="text-center lg:text-justify  ">Upgrade to premium speakers that are phenomenally built to deliver truly remarkable sound. </p>
    <button className="mt-4 w-1/2 h-11    rounded-xl  bg-black hover:scale-105 ease-in duration-500 lg:w-36 ">
      Shop Now
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    )
}
```

// Navbar

```
import React from "react";
import cart from "../assets/images/cart.png"
import { TfiMenu } from "react-icons/tfi";
import { AiOutlineCloseCircle} from "react-icons/ai";
export default function Navbar()
{
const [open,setopen]=React.useState(false)
    let Links =[
        {name:"Home" ,link:"/"},
        {name:"Headphone" ,link:"/"},
        {name:"Speaker" ,link:"earphones"},
        {name:"Earphone"  ,link:"/"},
      
    ]
    const change=()=>{
        setopen(!open)

    }
    return(
    <>
    <div className=" z-5000 fixed shadow-md w-full  top-0 left-0 ">
    <div className="  lg:flex items-center bg-black py-4 md:justify-around">
   <div className=" flex justify-between px-3 pt-2  text-white cursor-pointer font-[Poppins]">audiophile
   <div onClick={change} className=" lg:hidden  w-9 inline-block  ">
    {open ?     <span  className=""><AiOutlineCloseCircle/></span>:    <span  className=""><TfiMenu/></span>}


   </div>
   </div>
   <ul className={`lg:flex md:items-center ${open ?"" :"hidden"}  `}>
    {
        Links.map((link)=>(
            <li className='  my-7  ml-8 text-xl '> 
        <a href={link.link} className='text-white hover:text-yellow-500 duration-500'>{link.name}</a>
        </li>
        ))
        
    }
   </ul>
   <div className>
<img className="absolute right-20   md:inline-block  w-7 cursor- top-5 " src={cart} alt="cart" />
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </>
    )
}
```

//Home where all home components are rendered

```
import React from "react";
import Marktwo from "../Homecomponents/Marktwo";

import Listpage from "../Homecomponents/Listpage";
import Zspeaker from "../Homecomponents/Zspeaker";

export default function Home()
{
    return(
        <div>
     <Marktwo /> 
     <Listpage />
     <Zspeaker />
     <Zspeaker />
     <Zspeaker />
  
     </div>
    )
}
```

Whenever i try to make my div it makes the image of that particular div overlap over navbar when i scroll[Like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enBcV.png)
my github link this
project:https://github.com/athulmekkoth/ecom/tree/master/client
.........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Try setting a `z-index` on your navbar. e.g. `className="z-10"`. [Tailwind CSS | z-index](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/z-index)

Comment: hey i tried but not working

Comment: At this point, could you also add the code for your navbar and the container to which they are children??